# Why was "Belgium" Anglicized as such?

Tags: etymology, belgium

The country of Belgium derives its name from *Gallia Belgica*, the Roman province.  This led to "België" in Dutch, "Belgique" in French, and "Belgium" in English.

Why was the Latin word Anglicized this way?  I know of no other "-ium" countries, but plenty of "-a" and "-ia" countries.  So why wasn't "Belgica" left as-is for the new country's English name?  It's a perfectly comfortable pronunciation for English-speakers.  Or why not "Belgia" or "Belgicia," to match the common "-ia" pattern?

[Wiktionary gives *Belgium* as the proper declension of *Belgae*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Belgium#Etymology), the tribe for whom the province was named.  This makes sense, but it would seem  to be the only example in all the world.  Were no other countries named for tribes known to the Romans?  Or were they all Anglicized by a different pattern?

One can speculate that it was a juvenile suggestion by some starhopping truant in 1830, [the word "Belgium" being terribly offensive in the rest of the galaxy](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Belgium).

Comment: Belgium is a Latin synonym for Belgica; "proper declension" isn't a real thing. It was "anglicised" "as-is" from that form. And it is certainly not the "only" -ium place name. I can think of (1) The City of the World's Desires: [Byzantium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantium), (2) Homeland of the Latins: [Latium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latium), (3) The Isle of the Blest: [Elysium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium), and (4) [Londonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Londinium). They were simply less common than -a ending proper nouns to begin with and hence much fewer survived.

Comment: But none of those are in current English use for a real place.

Comment: Not a history question this is a linguistic question.

Comment: You might want to ask at [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com). They are probably better equipped to handle etymology questions.

Comment: @PiterGeerkens: no, because I'm not asking about the etymology of the word "Belgium;" it's addressed on Wiktionary. What I'm asking is *why* Belgium was named this way. Linguistics is not generally interested in how things came to be, but that's central to history. Note that there are over a dozen other questions on the site tagged [etymology].

Comment: @JonofAllTrades All of them are in current English use for historical writings. Besides, just because similar naming styles have died out doesn't mean we're going to renamed established placenames.

Comment: @Semaphore: of course. But Belgium was named very recently, in 1830, in a pattern that no (existing) country uses. There surely are some cities using this pattern, but Londinium and Byzantium are not good examples because they are several hundred years out of currency. "Belgium" is quite unique; why?

Comment: No, that is very wrong. 1830 was when Belgium became an independent state, not when it was named. And the word is directly adopted from a Latin word, **just like *many* other place names** even today. I don't know why you expect Latin-literate writers to deliberately misspell the word, *even if* no other -ium proper nouns were in currency at the time.

Comment: @Semaphore: whenever a new country comes to be, each language finds an appropriate label for it. Certainly there are always precedents to be followed or ignored, such as the official name(s) adopted by the country's government. The word "Belgium" is very old, yes, but that by no means made it inevitable that the English language word for the new country would be that; many countries' native names are quite mangled in English. If you know why this unique form was preferred by the Belgian or British governments (presuming they had the most influence over what word was selected), please share.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that "Belgium" was an entirely proper Latin name. The Union of Utrecht in 1579 called itself the "Belgium Foederatum", and writers used that exact same name in English. Just like Byzantium became Byzantium in English. There is nothing unique about it at all. It simply wasn't "Anglicised".